# LINQ: grouping by a property in a nested list

Tags: c#, linq, nested, grouping

Sorry for the somewhat vague title! I'm quite new to this grouping thing so please don't kill me for learning ;-)

I have these 2 classes:

```
public class chartItem
{
    public int prodID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public List<SubItem> SubItems { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class SubItem
{
    public int SubID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I'm having a hard time to explain what i'm trying to achieve so i attached a picture which says it all:

[image]

As you can see i'm trying to convert this input into this output using LINQ.

I have some code that comes near the wanted result, but I can't figure out the right way to do it (is it even possible)?:

```
list<chartItem> chartItems = new List<chartItem>();
... input data ...

chartItems = chartItems.GroupBy(x => new 
{ 
    prodID = x.prodID, qntity = x.SubItems.Count }, (key, val) => 
    new chartItem
    {
        prodID = key.prodID,
        Quantity = val.Count(),
        SubItems = val.First().SubItems
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you trying to group by `SubItems` ? I don't understand the picture you attached.

Comment: It looks like your primary problem is that you need an equality comparer that will compare two `chartItem` instances *including their subitems.* See this `GroupBy` overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534334(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @JimMischel I'll google some examples and see if I can go from there.